# SVN : multi user working copy setup

Tags: svn

I know this is a terrible setup but I cannot do anything about it. I just have a conceptual question I believe.

If I have multiple users working on the same checkout, when I do svn diff , I can only see if file X has been modified, not whether it has been modified by User 1 or User 2, correct?

Is there anyway to tell which User made the change to the file in a shared working copy? I assume no but I am a beginner at svn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Subversion point of view, all you have is a file that's compared on demand with a copy of the original—the concept of "modified by" does not exist until you commit changes. If the operating system itself doesn't track who modifies a file (and I don't think any of the major players do), there's no way to know.

I'm sorry but whoever decided you wouldn't use proper tools made quite a good job ;-)

Comment: Believe me if I had any authority, it would be different.

Comment: @lostinthebits - I feel sorry for you!